# Zenith angle calculation

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to reproduce the calculation of the zenith angle with respect to the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElYyQ.png), having two points in a same plane and a third one in the second plane. The points are represented as coordinates $(x,y,z)$. With the final derivation of the zenith angle as the equation below.

$$zenith = \frac{\pi}{2} - \theta = \frac{\pi}{2} - tan^{-1}\left (\frac{\sqrt{(x_{2}-x_{1})^{2}+(z_{2}-z_{1})^{2}}}{y_{2}-y_{1}}\right )$$
My question is how is this formula derived since two point in the upper plane have different z-value even do they are ate the same plane? having defined that the plane in the picture is xy.
I have only reached to the definition of:

$$tan\ (\theta) = \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$$

With the angle $\theta$ being the one from $(x_{2},y_{2},z_{2})$ to $(x_{2},y_{1},z_{2})$. The complete info can be found in the next [link](https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/1471233).

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! You do not ask a question in your question. Please clarify what precisely you are asking.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The diagram is poorly drawn.
As you observed, the diagram makes the triangle *appear* to be parallel to the $x,y$ plane even though this can only be true if $z_1 = z_2.$
In the general case we should not assume $z_1 = z_2,$ and therefore we should not assume that the triangle is parallel to the $x,y$ plane.

However, the edge of the triangle that appears to be parallel to the $y$ axis actually is parallel to the $y$ axis: the $x$ and $z$ coordinates at each end match the $x$ and $z$ coordinates at the other end.
The length of this edge is $\lvert y_2 - y_1\rvert.$

Another edge of the triangle has the same $y$ coordinate at each end, so it is parallel to the $x,z$ plane and perpendicular to the first edge;
that is, the triangle is a right triangle.
The length of this edge is $\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2 + (z_2-z_1)^2}.$

If $\theta$ is one of the acute angles of a right triangle,
a formula for $\tan(\theta)$ is $opp/adj$ where $opp$ is the length of the leg "opposite" the angle $\theta$ (the side that does not meet the angle's vertex)
and $adj$ is the length of the leg "adjacent" to the angle (the side that joins the angle's vertex to the right angle).

The angle $\theta$ in your triangle is evidently meant to be at the vertex $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$.

The formula $\tan(\theta) = \Delta y/\Delta x$ only works for a triangle that is in the $x,y$ plane where the adjacent leg is parallel to the $x$ axis.
Your triangle is not in the $x,y$ plane, and the adjacent leg is parallel to the $y$ axis. So you need a different formula.

In your case the adjacent leg is the side of length $\lvert y_2 - y_1\rvert$
and the opposite leg is the side of length $\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2 + (z_2-z_1)^2}.$
Therefore

$$ \tan(\theta) = \frac{\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2 + (z_2-z_1)^2}}{\lvert y_2 - y_1\rvert}. $$

Then

$$ \theta = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2 + (z_2-z_1)^2}}
                                {\lvert y_2 - y_1\rvert}\right). $$

There is one other problem with the formula and the figure.
The formula you wrote has only $y_2 - y_1$ in the denominator,
not $\lvert y_2 - y_1\rvert.$
If we are to believe the direction of the $y$ axis in the diagram,
$y_1 > y_2$ and therefore $y_2 - y_1$ is a negative number.
We therefore have a positive number divided by a negative number, which gives a negative result.
According to the definition of $\tan^{-1},$ if the input to the function is a negative number then the output is a negative angle.
So your formula shows a negative angle subtracted from $\frac\pi2,$
which results in an angle greater than $\frac\pi2.$
It seems unlikely that this is what was intended, so there is probably an error somewhere, either in the formula or in the diagram.

Another reason to suspect an error in the formula is that a zenith angle is normally measured relative to the vertical direction, which according to the diagram should be parallel to the $y$ axis. So the zenith angle should simply be equal to the angle of the triangle in the figure at $(x_2,y_2,z_2).$
But instead we are told to subtract that angle from a right angle.
As far as I can see, that would not give a zenith angle at all, but instead would give the angle of *elevation* from a plane parallel to the $x,z$ plane.
But it is also possible that this is an error of terminology,
and that the authors actually do want an angle of elevation and have simply misnamed it. One could only decide this by looking into the paper carefully.

Comment: So, this is only valid when $z_{1} \neq z_{2}$.

Comment: No, it's equally valid for any $z_1$ and $z_2.$ If $x_1=x_2$ and $z_1=z_2$ then you end up with $\theta = \tan^{-1}(0) = 0,$ which says the line from $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ to $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ goes straight up. But I still have doubts about whether the difference $y_2-y_1$ is correctly written in the formula in the question.